# use autocomplete textview with contacts phone number

Tags: android, autocomplete, sms, android-contacts, phone-number

I am having making my edittext field autocomplete for contacts phone numbers.  I know how to get contacts from database and display them in text field but i need them to autocomplete just incase the user wants to type a name into textfield.  I understand how to get an array to auto complete and the whole theory behind that.  But how to pull from phone contacts is difficult.  I've seen many tutorials and also various question on stack overflow, but still kind of stumped. A code snippit would help please.

```
public class MyContacts extends Activity {

    AutoCompleteTextView txtPhoneNo;

    public ArrayList<String> c_Name = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> c_Number = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] name_Val = null;
    String[] phone_Val = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        txtPhoneNo = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);

    }

    Uri contacts = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    Cursor managedCursor1 = cr.query(contacts, null, null, null, null);
    {
        if (managedCursor1.moveToFirst()) {

            String contactname;
            String cphoneNumber;

            int nameColumn = managedCursor1.getColumnIndex("name");
            int phoneColumn = managedCursor1.getColumnIndex("number");

            Log.d("int Name", Integer.toString(nameColumn));
            Log.d("int Number", Integer.toString(phoneColumn));

            do {
                // Get the field values
                contactname = managedCursor1.getString(nameColumn);
                cphoneNumber = managedCursor1.getString(phoneColumn);
                if ((contactname != " " || contactname != null)
                        && (cphoneNumber != " " || cphoneNumber != null)) {

                    c_Name.add(contactname);
                    c_Number.add(cphoneNumber);
                }

            } while (managedCursor1.moveToNext());
        }
        name_Val = (String[]) c_Name.toArray(new String[c_Name.size()]);
        phone_Val = (String[]) c_Number.toArray(new String[c_Name.size()]);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, name_Val);
        txtPhoneNo.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

My code... no compile errors but still does not work

Comment: can u explian what u want to do ?

Comment: Something very similar, to the autocomplete textview that is standard with any Android phone, when you text message

Comment: have you solve your problem?If solve then post your answer and accept it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better would be to fetch the Contacts and store it in `ArrayList`. Then you can just bind the ArrayList with the `AutoComplete` TextView. Then the rest of the part is just easy to filter the ArrayList when you the user types in the `AutoComplete` TextView.

**UPDATE**

You can create a POJO Class with getter-setter of `contact_name` and `contact_number`. Then create `List<POJO> list = new ArrayList<POJO>();`. Then just add the contact_name and contact_number to the `list` using `POJO` class

```
POJO pojo_obj = new POJO();
pojo_obj.setcontact_name(contactname);
pojo_obj.setcontact_number(cphoneNumber);
list.add(pojo_obj);
```

And finally set this `list` to the `Adapter`.

And then in the Adapter class you can set it to the TextView using

```
list.get(position).getcontact_name();
list.get(position).getcontact_number();
```

Comment: I posted my code, do you think you may be able to show me what you mean?

Comment: Thank you, ill try out. and i will post here and tell you if it works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724842/auto-suggest-contact-numbers-from-phone-contacts-android

Answer (score 0):

I think you are testing in the SDK.  The SDK doesn't have a SIM card and therefore won't work.  Put the .APK into the phone and try again.  It should work like a charm.

Comment: I have been testing it on my htc inspire. and it hasnt been working? did it work for you when/if you tried it?  If it worked for you then that would help.

Comment: Yes that worked for me in my Samsung Galaxy 3 Android 2.1.
Btw, you can try out this webpage which has a better way of extracting contacts .. [this link does a god job](http://coderzheaven.com/2011/06/get-all-details-from-contacts-in-android/)